# Increasing depth in Dendogram d3

Tags: d3.js, nested, data-visualization

In this example : [d3 layout tree](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111018/tree.html)

how to increase the depth of the tree? My json has even more nesting. The values beyond 3rd level branching dont appear. I have till the 5th level.

Sample json data:

```
{
 "name": "A",
 "children":[
    {
        "name": "B", 
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "C", 
                "children": [
                    [
                        {
                            "name": "D", 
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "name": "2008"
                                }
                            ]
                        }, 
                        {
                            "name": "E", 
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "name": "23"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                ]
            }

        ]
    }
    ]
}
```

Comment: can we see the json? and maybe can you reproduce it in a fiddle?

Comment: @echonax added a sample json data

Comment: I don't know if your whole JSON is valid but this is not a valid JSON. Check the syntax from http://jsonlint.com/.

Comment: @echonax May not be but I just need the logic... I will modify the json

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewpatt24/ctz358f6/ check this fiddle